# Do catalog price rules refresh when product prices are updated (using magmi) and reindexed?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions

This isn't a question about why do my catalog price rules disappear after midnight, that's usually to do with the cron not being setup correctly.

My query is just that a query.

Do catalog price rules refresh when product prices are updated (using magmi) and reindexed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, catalog price rules will update according to product prices....

Comment: Thanks, but do you still have to press **Save and Apply** each time new prices are added? I just wanted to check as it seems like this didn't happen to all the products.

Comment: @arun_silvertoad for my knowledge , no need to press `save and apply` when you change product prices, but when you change `catalog prive rules` you need to press `save and apply`, you can test this with by changing one test product price......

Comment: @arun_silvertoad please accept an answer once it worked for you....